# Do I treat this as an array or a hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, model

I have two models: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` and `class Tips < ActiveRecord::Base`. If I write:

```
user.each do |...|
```

or

```
tips.each.do |...|
```

Should I treat either as an array or a hash? How will I know?

I would post the model for user and tips, but they are very long. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think you mean `users.each` rather than `user.each` ?

Answer (score 1):

Objects inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` are ActiveRecord Objects and should be treated as such. A comprehensive list of methods can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). You can optionally convert AR objects to arrays (using the `.to_a` built-in) or hashes (by using your own hash implementation depending on how you want the keys and values)

Comment: My `user` model `has-many tips`. Can I then say `user.tips.to_a` to create an array of tips?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to specify a specific user to get all their tips. ie: `@user.tips.to_a`

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be improved in many ways. If I understood correctly:

You have a class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tips
  ...
end

class Tip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

So if you have an instance of class Tip (The class should be singular, unless every instance of this class represents many Tips) - let's call this instance @tip - it belongs_to only one user. So @tip.user will be really this one user - nothing to iterate through (nothing like a Hash or an Array). But the user itself has many tips. So @user.tips is something like an array. Although @user.tips is not an array (just try out in rails console something like:

```
@user = User.first
@user.tips.class
```

), it behaves in most cases like an array. If you need a real Array here, you can use

```
@user.tips.to_a
```

but in most cases you should stick with the association itself.

Answer (score 0):

For what it seems you're trying to do, treat it as an array.  In fact, you can do `User.all.to_a`, and it'll be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages vary as to their exact meaning of "array" *vs.* "hash," but Ruby *(unlike PHP, say ...)* follows Perl:

- A "hash" is a collection of things, indexed by an arbitrary "key."
- An "array" is an ordered collection of things, indexed by an integer.

Therefore, "what makes the most *sense,* for *you,* in *this* case?"  If "this collection-of-things is naturally 'ordered,' such that the "most comfy" way to think of it is "#1, #2, #3 ...," then a Ruby `array` would be called for.  Whereas, if one would (instead) ordinarily think of, "the entry for 'Tom,' 'Dick,' or 'Harry,'" the best representation would be a `hash`.

Superficially, since I see no obvious "key," the best answer is probably:  an `array`.